# Troubleshooting Xilinx IP Core CPRI Link Between Master and Slave

Tags: fpga, xilinx

I am currently facing a technical issue with my Xilinx project involving the CPRI link between the master and slave devices. Here's a breakdown of the problem:

In a single test loopback setup, both external and internal CPRI master loopbacks, the stat_code reads "1111," which is the expected behavior.
However, when I connect the SFP on the master to the slave board, I'm encountering a peculiar situation. Only at a specific bitrate, the stat_code reads "1111," and the link successfully comes up, but after a noticeable delay.
At all other speeds, I'm unable to achieve L1 sync, and the stat_code remains stuck at "0001."
Furthermore, when I connect the slave to an external BBU, none of the bitrates can establish L1 sync.
I am seeking guidance and insights to resolve this issue. If anyone has experience with Xilinx IP Core, CPRI links, and FPGA technologies, your expertise would be greatly appreciated. Any suggestions, troubleshooting tips, or insights into what might be causing this issue would be invaluable.

Thank you for taking the time to read this question, and I look forward to any assistance or advice you can provide.

- Checked the configuration and settings of the Xilinx IP Core for CPRI in both the master and slave devices to ensure they are properly configured.
- Verified that the physical connections between the master and slave devices, including the SFP link, are secure and correctly set up.
- Attempted to adjust various bitrate settings and parameters to see if the issue is related to specific data rates.
- Reviewed the relevant documentation and manuals for the Xilinx IP Core and CPRI to troubleshoot the issue.
- Sought advice from colleagues and online resources but haven't found a solution yet.

I expected that after configuring the Xilinx IP Core CPRI link, the master and slave devices would establish a reliable and stable connection at various data rates. Specifically, I was hoping for L1 synchronization to occur consistently across different bitrates, and I expected the stat_code to reflect this synchronization. However, I'm currently experiencing the issues described in my initial post.